# How to renew Server CA Certificate on Google Cloud MySQL

Tags: mysql, ssl, google-cloud-sql

I have created an SSL using the Console following the documentation given [here](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/configure-ssl-instance), that was a little over a year ago.  Since then I have been using MySQL Workbench using the three files that were created to connect to the server via SSL.

This morning I started to receive the error: "SSL connection error: ASN: after date in the past".  After further investigation I found out that the NotAfter date in the Server-CA.pem file was 10/09/2016.  The NotAfter date on the Cert.pem file is 06/07/2017.  How can I renew the Server-CA.pem file so that my SSL is still valid?

Comment: Just encountered the same thing... used "Reset SSL Configuration", which re-generated the CA cert, but also revoked all client keys *and* restarted the instance. Yuck.

Comment: Yea I am hoping there is a solution that would not require a reboot on the instance.

Comment: Agree - such invasive manual maintenance operation is not justified even on the yearly basis.

Should be automatic or two years minimum.